# Conditions on has_many in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Post model that has_many :authors and has_many :tags through :tag_posts, an Author model that has_many :posts and has_many :tags through :posts, and a Tag model that has_many :posts through :tag_posts.

Posts have to pass moderation (stored as an enum Post.status) before they're visible on the site. Moderators can see unmoderated posts by looking for ones with a different Post.status, but regular users should never be able to see them.

Is there any way I can filter all these associations to make sure they only return the posts that moderators have approved?

For example: if I call Author#tags now, that returns all the tags on all the posts that author has written, but I only want it to return the tags on the *approved* posts that the author has written. Say the author has two posts, the first is approved and is tagged 'octopus', and the second hasn't been approved yet and is tagged 'squid': calling #tags on that author should only return the octopus tag, not the squid tag.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Post model that has_many :authors and has_many :tags through :tag_posts, an Author model that has_many :posts and has_many :tags through :posts, and a Tag model that has_many :posts through :tag_posts.

First thing's first, let's tidy up those relations. I believe this is what you really want:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author  # NOT has_many
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags # use an implicit join table
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts # use an implicit join table
end
```

> Is there any way I can filter all these associations to make sure they only return the posts that moderators have approved?

Yes. Without going into to much detail, the key technique is to define a `scope` on the `Post` model; something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :approved -> { where(status: Post.statuses['approved']) }
end
```

You can then show only the approved posts via `Post.approved`; or only the approved posts for a certain user via `Post.where(user: foo).approved`.

In order the display a list of tags, you could then, for example, just do:

```
Post.where(user: foo).approved.map(&:tags).uniq
```

This will only give you an `Array`, not an `ActiveRecord::Collection`. But that's probably good enough, for your purposes.

Comment: Right, I should've been clearer -- multiple authors can contribute to one post. The posts-authors and posts-tags join tables are both explicit now, to make it easier to add tag ordering, distinct author credits, etc. later. Getting an ActiveRecord::Collection would be ideal, since the author's view page should link to the tags; that can be done with custom SQL, but I'm hoping there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can scope `has_many` itself. 
Eg.

```
class Author
  has_many :moderated_posts, -> { moderated }, class_name: 'Post' 
end

class Post
  scope :moderated, -> { where(status: approved_statuses) }
end
```